# Marketing Cloud Ampscript Lookup variable

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

**UPDATE**I found the problem.
 - entrysource Journey = salesforce data event (which automatically creates 2 Example DataExtension with headers = service cloud fields) 
 - from this journey I send the email with the link to the CloudPage
 - I debugged the code below and the error message said: in order for the ampscript to work, the ID attributes in the sourceDE need to have a maximum #
   of characters specified
 - Because the data extension is system generated, it is not possible to
   change the maximum # of characters for the ID attributes (or delete them)

**NEW QUESTION**
*IT SEEMS CHANGING THE ATTRIBUTE FROM DATA DESIGNER IS TAKING A VERY LONG TIME. IS THERE ANOTHER WAY TO CHANGE THE ATTRIBUTES?**

**OLD QUESTION**
I'm sending an email with a cloudpage link. On that cloudpage smartcapture I want to pre-fill a hidden attribute with the AccountId from that data extension. The data extension name is "2 Example DataExtension", the column header is Account:Id, the subscriberkey column header is Account:PersonContact:Id, subscriberkey is PersonContactId.

```
%%[var @subscriberKey, @dataSourceName, @subscriberId, @listName, @debug, 
@Id
set @debug = RequestParameter("debug")
set @subscriberKey = AttributeValue("_subscriberKey")
set @dataSourceName = AttributeValue("_DataSourceName")
set @subscriberId = AttributeValue("subscriberid")
set @listName = AttributeValue("_listname")
if empty(@subscriberKey) then
set @Id = ""
else
set @Id = Lookup("2 Example DataExtension", "Account:Id", 
"Account:PersonContact:Id", @subscriberKey)
endif
]%%
```

The value in the hidden attribute: %%=v(@Id)=%%

The name of the attribute I will be sending the Account:Id to when I click Submit on the SmartCapture is named Id.

What needs to be improved in my code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! You are asking [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What's your intended purpose? Do you have any issues with your implementation or why do your want to improve it?

Comment: I am pre-filling the subscriberkey (PersonContactId), which works fine. But I also want to pre-fill the Account Id, when I try with above code it doesn't work. The goal is to perform an Update Account Object Activity (Journey), therefore I need the Account Id.

Comment: I have tried to execute v() function in the hidden attribute part in smart capture form and it didn't work. Maybe you can create a manual form with HTML and prefill the form fields that you want.

Comment: Thank you! I have narrowed it down.
- entrysource Journey = salesforce data event (automatically creates 2 Example DataExtension with headers = service cloud fields)
- Because the data extension is system generated, it is not possible to change the maximum # of characters for the ID attributes
- in order for the ampscript to work, the ID attributes need to have a maximum # of characters specified.

I am now trying to edit the max # of characters via data designer, hope that works
-